# ICCPR article 26 "birth or other status"

Tags: legal-terms, human-rights, definition

What does birth or other status mean in [Article 26 of International Covenant on Civil and Political Rights](https://www.ohchr.org/en/instruments-mechanisms/instruments/international-covenant-civil-and-political-rights)?

Does it have the same connotation as "political or other opinion" in that the terms birth and other status is to be read together?

Answer (score 2):

"Birth or other status" are just the final two entries in the list identifying who is protected under [Article 26](https://www.ohchr.org/en/instruments-mechanisms/instruments/international-covenant-civil-and-political-rights) ICCPR:

> All persons are equal before the law and are entitled without any discrimination to the equal protection of the law. In this respect, the law shall prohibit any discrimination and guarantee to all persons equal and effective protection against discrimination on any ground **such as** race, colour, sex, language, religion, political or other opinion, national or social origin, property, birth or other status.

"*Such as*" indicates the list is not exhaustive, so "*other status*" could, for example, refer to marriage or civil partnership.

And the lack of a comma in "*political or other opinion*" just groups those two together as related characteristics.

Comment: The lack of an Oxford comma between "birth" and "or" is just a punctuation convention and it has the same meaning that it would if the Oxford common were present there.